# Como puedo crear un trigger que se ejecute dinamicamente sobre todas las tablas de un schema en oracle

Tags: oracle

```
   <code>
    create or replace procedure p_generar_triggers 
    is
    
    tabla VARCHAR2(10) := 'b_areas';
    encabezado VARCHAR2(100) := 'create  trigger t_';
    v_sentencia VARCHAR2( 8000) ; 
    v_event VARCHAR2(1000) := ' after insert or update or delete  on ';
    v_body varchar2(1000);
    
    begin
     encabezado := encabezado || tabla;
     v_event := v_event || tabla;
     v_body := q'[ for each row 
    
    declare 
    begin 
    if INSERTING then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Aca insertara datos '); 
    end if;    
    end ]';
    
    v_sentencia := encabezado ||v_event||v_body;
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sentencia);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sentencia;
    exception
    when others then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ocurrio un error inesperado  '|| sqlerrm);
    end;
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Cree el procedimiento test_trigger que recorrerá las tablas del 
esquema y creará dinámicamente un trigger con la denominación
T_<nombre_tabla> que deberá dispararse para todas las tablas después de 
la inserción, borrado o modificación de datos

Este es el problema del ejercicio

Comment: ¿Y entonces cuál es la pregunta  o la duda?